# Notification of impending new privilege

Tags: feature-request, notifications, privileges

On the Android SE App, I just noticed this morning that a user gets a notification to inform them they are *X rep away from Y* privilege:

[image: Click for large image]

I thought this was a really neat feature and it certainly encourages me to try that bit harder to get there.

Should we have the same feature on the desktop version too? Not just for the obvious benefit of potentially increasing the amount of community-minded individuals out there, but also for consistency across all platforms.

To clarify, I think it should display in the notification drawer:

[image: Example]

It would be great if could only show for a limited period of time, maybe even drop down onto a new line too to show how much rep left until the target, although I feel it works equally well without these.

Comment: But what is your suggested design? Where will we see the notification? In the app it's only a temporary feed, it won't stick anywhere but in the top bar notifications, once you get one it stays in there until pushed down by newer notifications. That's where you want to see it?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Updated with an example design. I understand the app is a temporary feed, but I don't see an issue with it being a notification and being tied to a single date. I know I would see that and think "I was close to that privilege 7 days ago" the same as I do when I see a badge in there